# Jira - filter for subtasks where parent has X criteria

Tags: jira, jql

I want to create a filter to see al issues and their subtasks where the parent belongs to component X. I cannot use any plugins to accomplish this.

Comment: Im afraid but without a plugin, probably not possible. As far as i know. If you could use scriptrunner plugin, let me know and it would be just a moment

Answer (score 0):

Native Jira JQL is going to come up short.  Your best bet is extending the existing JQL Functions with [Script Runner](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner/server/overview), and running something like this:

```html
component = "Active Directory" and issueFunction in hasSubtasks()
```